# Yii2 BaseImage Unable to open image

Tags: image, yii2, thumbnails

When i'm trying to make a thumbnail form uploaded image yii2 says "Unable to open image ../../../content/curses/a/8/Penguins.jpg". It works on localhost, but it does not works server.

Answer (score 0):

[full Yii2 path aliases list](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/)

Build your links/paths and so on, with Yii2 aliases to avoid errors like this.

Comment: i build links with  Yii2 aliases but it still returns error."Unable to open image..."
\yii\imagine\Image::thumbnail(\Yii::getAlias('@app').'/'.$fileName, 300, 195)->save(\Yii::getAlias('@app').'/images/'.$fileName);

Comment: @as give the read/write rights to the imagine / images folders as that can cause the errors.

Comment: @as you don't have permissions set, or you path is wrong. Test the same path with other script. Like simple upload or smth.

Comment: i was trying to set permissions before using Image::thumbnail with chmod( $folder . $fileName, 0770 );. and the path is correct because firs I do upload image in   $folder . $fileName destination.

Comment: @ast try to set 0777 and check the result

Comment: I found an error. It is because of php does not support JPEG.
Because it works with PNG. 
Thank's a lot  for your answers.

Comment: @ast hmm i`m happy it`s working, but php don`t have any problems with .jpeg files